# Passing function to class in C++

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, std-function

I want to store a function in a class and simply call this function inside a member function. I know that this is possible using function pointers but I want to use `std::function` for this.

Here is some code that is not working but should demonstrate what I want to do:

```
double foo(double a, double b){
    return a + b;
}


class Test{
 private:
        std::function<double(double,double)> foo_ ;
 public:
        Test(foo);
        void setFoo(foo) {foo_ = foo;}
        double callFoo(double a, double b){return foo_(a,b);}
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Test bar = Test(foo);
    bar.callFoo(2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Here is some code that is not working* it's usually a good idea to specify how/why it's not working. Not compiling? If so provide the error. Runtime error? Provide callstack and/or error. Wrong output? Provide input/outpout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost did it right, but forgot the types in your constructor and `setFoo`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

double foo(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}

class Test {
private:
    std::function<double(double, double)> foo_;
public:
    // note the argument type is std::function<>
    Test(const std::function<double(double, double)> & foo) : foo_(foo) {}
    // note the argument type is std::function<> 
    void setFoo(const std::function<double(double, double)>& foo) { foo_ = foo; }
    double callFoo(double a, double b) { return foo_(a, b); }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Test bar = Test(foo);
    bar.callFoo(2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, it is often beneficial to use a typedef to avoid long and complicated names, for example if you do

```
typedef std::function<double(double,double)> myFunctionType
```

you can use `myFunctionType` everywhere, which is easier to read (provided you invent a better name than "myFunctionType") and more tidy.